# How can I get multiple workspaces in Kubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu

I find KDE for Kubuntu 13.10 is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use multiple desktops in Kubuntu. You should go to System Settings >> Personal >> Desktops >> Multiple Desktops. Here's an official quick guide on basic settings: http://www.kubuntu.org/docs/kquickguide/C/ch03s07.html#desktop-multipledesktops

Now, if you find KDE annoying, maybe you should try another desktop environment, such as Unity. I believe you don't need to reinstall your system to get a new desktop environment running... installing the appropriate packages should do. See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/165803/169250 (**Note:** I've never done this, so I don't know if that really works!)

Comment: My problem was that there is no System Settings >> Personal in my version of KDE that came with Kubuntu 13.10.  However, I did eventually find System Settings >> Workspace Appearance and Behavior >> Workspace Behavior >> Virtual Desktops >> Number of desktops (this is rather obvious now: it works).  Note that switching desktops is no longer done with Alt+Ctrl+arrow-key, but with Ctrl+F1, Ctrl+F2, Ctrl+F3, etc. (see the Switching tab).  Also, moving the mouse wheel over a desktop switches desktops, which isn't mentioned anywhere that I can see.

Comment: I'm annoyed too. It was the KDE default for ages to have multiple workspaces in and a switcher in the panel. Now you have to excavate some settings deeply buried in the configurations, in two different places (activate workspaces & configure panel).

Comment: @user235885 I had the same thing.  In system settings searching for "desktops" it highlights only the settings that have what you searched for.  So, doing that I found it: Desktop Beahvior -> Virtual Desktops

Comment: "I believe you don't need to reinstall your system to get a new desktop environment running". Probably pointless to say this here in a comment on an old question, but this really bugs me. You always see people encouraging you "Oh yeah, you can install all the different desktop environments and switch between them to try them all out!" And that's bull. They interact *horribly*. Your file associations get messed up, the settings in, say, Lubuntu, will start messing with behaviors in Kubuntu, etc etc. Ugh.