# update-initramfs missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic

Tags: 16.04, kernel, initramfs

I just upgraded `linux-firmware` package and after that I used `$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` but I got some errors:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
[sudo] password for piotrek: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-13-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LJbkti/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LJbkti/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure I don't have kernel 4.4.0-13. I might have had it some time ago but removed it:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep linux-

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-base/xenial,xenial,now 4.0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
linux-firmware/now 1.159 all [installed,local]
linux-headers-4.4.0-31/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-31.50 all [installed]
linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-31.50 amd64 [installed]
linux-headers-4.4.0-34/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-34.53 all [installed]
linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-34.53 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-31.50 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-34.53 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-31.50 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-34.53 amd64 [installed]
linux-libc-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-34.53 amd64 [installed]
linux-sound-base/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all [installed]
syslinux-common/xenial,xenial,now 3:6.03+dfsg-11ubuntu1 all [installed]
syslinux-legacy/xenial,now 2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
```

How to fix those `update-initramfs` errors?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The utility `update-initramfs` looks in `var/lib/initramfs-tools`. You will find an entry for that old kernel there. Removing it:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-13-generic
```

will get rid of that error

(the locale issue is something else entirely...)

Comment: Ok thank you it worked. And I fixed locale with `sudo locale-gen --purge --no-archive` from this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/100519/56083

Comment: Does anyone know what creates the files in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools`?  And  when?  And why?  I'd like to know what causes the problem.

Comment: @mpb afaik, it is [created by update-initramfs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26226226/), which is called by APT (or `dpkg`?) when a kernel or driver is updated. But imho, you should ask a question about this

Comment: @Zanna, I moved all the files out of `/var/lib/initramfs-tools`, and ran `update-initramfs`.  It immediately exited.  I believe it  will update files that already exist there, but it will not create files that do not exist.  Additionally, it will only attempt to build  `initrd`s for kernel versions that already have files in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools`.  If I cared enough, I would post a separate question, but I have other tasks to work on.  Thanks!

Comment: didn't solve it for me. same issue here, but no old kernel.

Comment: @chris well, isn't that a different problem then? Have you asked a new question with the full details & output?

Comment: +1 but too bad @chris didn't post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. And I had to, in addition to the actions listed above, also delete all files related to the old kernels from /boot