# Error during update-initramfs -k all -u

Tags: drivers, kernel, initramfs

On my box (which got this error under 16.04 and it continues under 17.04...)

`Update-initramfs` looks for an uninstalled kernel it can't find.
`dpkg -l` does not show this... anyone know how to fix this leftover
reference somewhere?

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-62
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-62: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TQSiag/lib/modules/3.13.0-62/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TQSiag/lib/modules/3.13.0-62/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer...

[update-initramfs missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809947/update-initramfs-missing-lib-modules-4-4-0-13-generic)

That pointed me to the left-behind junk.

```
root@S20:/etc/depmod.d# cd /var/lib/initramfs-tools/
root@S20:/var/lib/initramfs-tools# ls
3.13.0-62  3.13.0-63  4.10.0-15-generic  4.8.0-46-generic
root@S20:/var/lib/initramfs-tools# rm -rf 3.13.0-6?
```